# KeyboardExtensions in CommunityToolkit.Maui to handle soft keyboard

Tags: maui, community-toolkit-maui

I'm using `CommunityToolkit.Maui` in my .NET MAUI app targeting .NET 8 to prevent soft keyboard from covering up user controls. It kind of works but still covers the `Entry` partially. Before I report this as an issue, I want to see if it has anyting to do with my layout.

I do use `Border` around my `Entry` controls for visual effect so I thought it might have something to do with that so I removed the `Border`'s but the results were identical.

Here's the before and after screenshots. And tapping into the password `Entry` produces a very similar result where half the `Entry` is still covered by the soft keyboard:

[image]

Here's the `LoginPage.xaml`:

```
<!-- Login Form -->
<Grid
    RowDefinitions="*,60,60,100,50"
    Padding="0">

    <!-- Background Image -->
    <Image
        Grid.RowSpan="5"
        Source="teton_snake_dimmed.jpg"
        Aspect="AspectFill" />

    <!-- 0: Logo -->
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Source="ingrid_connect_logo.png"
        HeightRequest="130"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <!-- 1: Username Entry -->
    <Border
        Grid.Row="1"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
        Padding="5"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Entry
            Text="{Binding UserName}"
            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Placeholder="Email Address"
            Focused="ShowKeyboard"
            Unfocused="HideKeyboard"
            Keyboard="Email"
            WidthRequest="350" />
    </Border>

    <!-- 2: Password Entry -->
    <Border
        Grid.Row="2"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
        Padding="5"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Entry
            Text="{Binding Password}"
            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            IsPassword="True"
            Placeholder="Password"
            Focused="ShowKeyboard"
            Unfocused="HideKeyboard"
            WidthRequest="350" />
    </Border>

    <!-- 3: Submit Button -->
    <Button
        Grid.Row="3"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        Text="S I G N    I N"
        FontSize="13"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
        HeightRequest="50"
        WidthRequest="350"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <!-- 4: Register/Forgot Password Links -->
    <HorizontalStackLayout
        Grid.Row="4"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <!-- New User Sign Up -->
        <Border
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            StrokeThickness="0"
            Padding="7">
            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding GoToSignUpCommand}"/>
            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label
                Text="New User Sign Up"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="12" />
        </Border>

        <!-- Seperator -->
        <Border
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            StrokeThickness="0"
            Padding="7">
            <Label
                Text="|"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="12"
                Margin="5,0,5,0" />
        </Border>

        <!-- Forgot Password -->
        <Border
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            StrokeThickness="0"
            Padding="7">
            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding GoToForgotPasswordCommand}"/>
            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label
                Text="Forgot Password"
                TextColor="White"
                FontSize="12" />
        </Border>

    </HorizontalStackLayout>

</Grid>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
private async void ShowKeyboard(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
    if (!KeyboardExtensions.IsSoftKeyboardShowing(entry))
        await KeyboardExtensions.ShowKeyboardAsync(entry, default);
}

private async void HideKeyboard(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
    if (KeyboardExtensions.IsSoftKeyboardShowing(entry))
        await KeyboardExtensions.HideKeyboardAsync(entry, default);
}
```

Is this my layout or an issue with `KeyboardExtensions` in `CommunityToolkit.Maui`?

P.S. My .NET MAUI app targets .NET 8 and I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 17.8.0 with the final .NET 8 release. Also the `CommunityToolkit.Maui` version is `7.0.0`.

Comment: I am not going to lie I am surprised to see this issue on Android, iOS is the one that creates these kinds of stupid issues, Anyway I was wondering are you showing and hiding the keyboard every time? If yes have you tried not using the extensions and seeing if Android is able to handle this on its own?

Comment: The issue is on `iOS`. As you said, `Android` doesn’t need any help. It handles it fine on its own.

Comment: Not sure if this will help a lot or not but check this out https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/

Comment: Here is a similar issue on SO : [.NET MAUI: entry hidden behind keyboard on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304124/net-maui-entry-hidden-behind-keyboard-on-ios).