# Can't access controls behind keyboard in .Net Maui page

Tags: c#, maui

I have several pages where I need the user to fill out lots of details. The problem I have is that I can't get to the controls at the bottom due to the keyboard. How do you work around this?

See below. I can't get to the 'Contact 3' details because the keyboard is in the way.

Thanks

[image: Keyboard hiding controls]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's sufficient to wrap your page content in ScrollView

If you need to shift the entire bottom area when keyboard is opened, use Grid at the top level and set the child container's VerticalOptions to "End":

```xml
<Grid>
   <VerticalStackPanel VerticalOptions="End">
      Some elements at the bottom that will be shifter by the keyboard and should stay visible
   </VerticalStackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I also suggest that you take a look at the free [DevExpres DataForm](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/403647/data-form/get-started) control thatay help you with many editing tasks, such as automatic layout generation, centralised validation and commit options.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to work. In fact I already had a scrollview in place but this change doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two workarounds that you can use to access the controls at the bottom due to the keyboard appears.

**#1 WORKAROUND:**

You can try to set the `Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` attached property to `Pan`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?> 
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp" 
                
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan"

             x:Class="MauiApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For more information, you can check [Soft keyboard input mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-7.0).

**#2 WORKAROUND:**

Suppose the input control is a `Entry`, you can add a `behavior` (or `attached property`) to allow users the ability to **close** the soft keyboard when clicking outside of a view which will enable you to access the controls at the bottom.

For more information, you can refer to [[Proposal] Add a behavior (or attached property) to allow users the ability to close the soft keyboard when clicking outside of a view #978](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/978).

```
<Entry Placeholder="Text Field" Text="Starting text" WidthRequest="300">
       <Entry.Behaviors>
             <local:SoftKeyboardBehavior CloseOnTapOutsideBounds="true"></local:SoftKeyboardBehavior>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

`Android`: https://github.com/PureWeen/ShanedlerSamples/tree/main/ShanedlerSamples/Library/TapToCloseBehavior
`iOS`: [dotnet/maui#10948](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/10948)

Workaround for **iOS**:
https://github.com/massijay/iOSMauiScrollUpOnKeyboardShow

Comment: Hi Alexandar. Unfortunately WindowSoftInputModeAdjust didn't make any difference (and looks like this is only for Android, so I would still have a problem, with iOS). The second suggestion doesn't really fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi BuckBuchanan. For iOS, you can refer to [Keyboard covering form elements on iOS on .NET MAUI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536074/keyboard-covering-form-elements-on-ios-on-net-maui-app). If possible,Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?